# Jinja2 formatting template using the dictionary of a dictionary values

Tags: python, templates, django-templates, jinja2, python-templates

I have the below content as a input to my jinja template:

```
{'run_test': {'NS': [], 'SS': [' Create']}, 'pre_test': {'MS': [], 'FI': [' Create'], 'FS': [' Create', ' size=10']}}
```

Here I have a dictionary which contains 2 keys: 
1. run_test 
2. pre_test

I have written a script where I want to populate the values of these keys.
Each key's value is a dictionary. This dictionary contains Key2 and value as list.
I want to generate a import statement in my script where I am using the text of key2. 
Example:
Here the expected output is:

```
from blabla import NS, SS, MS, FI, FS
```

Notice here NS, SS, MS, FI and FS are the key2 values.
Also the issue I am facing is with appending the commas. At the end of the string I don't want to add the comma.
My current code is:

```
from blabla import {% for key, val in content.items() -%}
{%- for obj in val -%}
  {%- if loop.last -%}
    {{ obj }}
  {%- else -%}
    {{ obj }},
   {%- endif -%}
   {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

And the output it returns is:

```
from blabla import NS
,SSMF
,FI,FS
```

Can someone please help me get the desired output in expected format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from blabla import {% for key, val in content.items() -%}
{% set outer_loop = loop %}
{%- for obj in val -%}
  {%- if loop.last and outer_loop.last -%}
    {{ obj }}
  {%- else -%}
    {{ obj }},<span> </span>
   {%- endif -%}
   {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

Whitespace outside of tags in HTML is generally ignored, so the `<span>` tags help insert the space after each comma. You also only want to skip the comma on the last element of inner loop in the last iteration of the outer loop. Creating the variable outer_loop allows you to do that.

Comment: It did not work for me. I tried your script and it returned me <br> `NS
,<span> </span>SS,<span> </span>MS
,<span> </span>FI,<span> </span>FS` . Note, I am not using these tags in .html, instead I am using it on .jinja2 template. I am trying to generate a dynamic python script here.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. I had '\n' in my dict, because of which it was creating problem. Once I fixed it, you code worked. Thanks a lot.